# re.sub with exception or condition

Tags: python, regex, replace, negation

I want to sub use re.sub to substitute all the words with parentheses but not the word (k), I want to use some negation conditions but it seems not working to my example.

I've tried

```
 \((?<!k)\w+\)
```

Is there any suggestions?

```
re.sub(r'\((?<!k)\w+\)', '', '(k) i am, us dep economy (applause) (ph)', flags= re.IGNORECASE)
```

Desired result would be

```
(k) i am, us dep economy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
\((?!k\))\w+\)
```

- `(?!k\)` makes sure `k)` does not come after the initial `(`

So:

```
In [75]: re.sub(r'\((?!k\))\w+\)', '', '(k) i am, us dep economy (applause) (ph)', flags= re.IGNORECASE)
Out[75]: '(k) i am, us dep economy  '
```

Comment: What does `w+` signify?

Comment: @haxtar Not `w+`, its `\w+`, which signifies one or more (`+`) of alphanumerics or underscore (`\w`).

Comment: @haxtar Not `w+`, its `\w+`, which signifies one or more (`+`) of alphanumerics or underscore (`\w`).